# Integration - Fundamental Theorem

Tags: integration

Find derivative of:

$F(x) = \int _0^x\:\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}dt$

My book's answer is $\sqrt{1+x^4}$ but I think it should be $F '(x)= \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$ because of the theorem.

Comment: You are right ! That's the answer

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea what your textbook was thinking...  You should be right!

Comment: What book and what exercise?

Comment: @mickep james stewart calculus 6th edition secton 5 review excersice 43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{\int_0^x\text{f}\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}=\text{f}\left(x\right)$$

So:

$$\text{F}'\left(x\right)=\text{f}\left(x\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\space\text{d}t\right\}=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$

Another way, is calculating the integral first:

$$\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\space\text{d}t=\int_0^x1\space\text{d}t-\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}\space\text{d}t=\left[t\right]_0^x-\left[\arctan\left(t\right)\right]_0^x=$$
$$\left(x-0\right)-\left(\arctan\left(x\right)-\arctan\left(0\right)\right)=x-\arctan\left(x\right)$$

So:

$$\text{F}'\left(x\right)=\text{f}\left(x\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left\{\int_0^x\frac{t^2}{1+t^2}\space\text{d}t\right\}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x-\arctan\left(x\right)\right)=1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: I didnt notice that, thanks